# cloth animation not working after adding loop cuts on the edges

Tags: cloth-simulation

so, I am making a scene, where I have a piece of paper, with a cloth animation on it.  (see image below)
[image]
I have a subdivision surface on the paper, but I want to have sharp corners.  My problem is, is that every time I add a loop cut to the mesh to get rid of the sharp corners, the cloth animation suddenly stops working.
[image]
working.  Does anyone know why this is happening.  And better yet, how to fix it?  thanks :)
[image]

Comment: It should not, maybe share your file?

Comment: Can't you just use the `Simple` option of the [Subdivision Surface modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html) to preserve the shape and keep the corners sharp?

Comment: @moonboots I put the file to my project above

Comment: It works fine here so I don't knows why it doesn't for you, I hope someone will help  :((

Comment: @Blunder I could use the "simple" option, but for the project I am making, I would prefer to have a lot smoother edges,  while still having sharp corners.

Comment: @moonboots thats really weird

Answer (score 0):

Another way to sharpen edges would be the "mean bevel crease". maybe try this.

[image]

btw: I added a file to the question you commented on. Not sure, whether you'd get notified of that. :)
[Cloth is colliding with some objects but not all](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201210/cloth-is-colliding-with-some-objects-but-not-all/201227#201227)